# how to get the right object of an array in the parent

Tags: api, vue.js, vue-component, emit

In my app I have a parent component which queries an api to fill an array of objects.
These objects with different properties are then passed to multiple child components with a v-for loop.
In a child component I can edit certain properties of the object via a form with textinputs.
Using @change I emit this to the parent, so I can edit the object there and post it to the api.
However, how do I find the right object in the array?

I could loop the array in the parent to find the right object based on the id (one of the properties), but that seems very slow to me. Is there a way to directly get the right object? Or do I make the api call for updates in the child component? That seems not logical, because the parent won't know the object changed?

Comment: I think you can pass your iterated object through `@change` i.e. `@change="update(item)"`.

Comment: Yes that is correct, that is what I do. But is the item the same one as the one in the array? If I have a method in my parent that changes a property of the object, is that the same as changing that property of the object in the array?

Comment: Usually yes. https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-goldwasser-1z8jz.

Comment: Ok great, thanks, the sandbox is clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Within the v-for loop you have access to the elements index within the array

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in items" @change="update(item, i)"></div>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
             myArray: [{}, {}]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        update(item, i) {
            this.myArray[i] = item
        }
    }


}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rfxtpua1/

Comment: My @change is somewhere in the child component, so that means that I should pass the index as a prop to the child and then use that in my emit method. 
That could work also I think. Interesting, thanks